# How to check if one of values is empty on JSON array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to assign autocomplete value for hiddenfield only if   'desc'  => $json_result["level"] getting empty result , else 
autofilter selected values should assign to a hidden field

**JSON**

```
       $json=array();
 foreach ($results as $json_result) {
 $json[] = array(
     'value' => $json_result["id"],
     'label' =>  $json_result["title"],
     'desc'  => $json_result["level"]
 );
}


 echo json_encode($json);
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function(){
              jQuery("#searchc").autocomplete({
                  source:'<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jomdirectory_search/tmpl/classified.php'; ?>',
                    delay: 300 ,

                  minLength:1,


                  select: function(event, ui) {

/*
```

> this place i need to check , whether the selected value have empty
>   value for     'desc'  => $json_result["level"] or not. if its having
>   empty values   jQuery('#categories_id').val(ui.item.value); this
>   assigning hidden field  part should remove and auto complete work by
>   default

*/

```
                      if (this.value = ui.item.label){
                      jQuery('#categories_id').val(ui.item.value);

                      return false;
                        }

                      if(this.desc == ""  ){
                          jQuery('#searchc').val(ui.item.desc);
                      }
                  }


              });


          });
```

**Form**

```
    <td> <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" id="searchc" name="searchc"   value="" required=""  /></td>

                <td><p>Location</p>
 <input type="hidden" id="categories_id" name="categories_id" value="" />
                    <input type="text" id="addressc" name="address"  /></td>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: assigning hidden field (category-id)  i want to limit . i want only the arrays which have empty value for    'desc'  => $json_result["level"] , when selecting aufofilter vlaue it shouldnot assign to a hidden field. currenty hidden field assign to all results. please advice me how to proceed

Comment: You will really need to explain better. Is there an error somewhere in your code? Maybe you need to use `if (typeof(this.desc)=="undefined")` to see if it is not set?

Comment: @D. Kasipovic : i put a note on my question where i need to check , please kindly check

Comment: Well, selected value is not `$(this)`, it is `ui.item`, so maybe you need to check `ui.item.desc` ?

Comment: yes @D. Kasipovic : if a selected item.value havent a .desc value in array , hiddenfield assinging part shouldnot work.. thats wht i want to do . pls help

Comment: I really can't figure out what you need.

Comment: @D. Kasipovic : ok , im doing a search where it inclued to autofulter both categories and items . if a autofilter selected value is category , i want to assign it to hidden field called categories_id where it give search results related to that category. but if a selected autofilter value is item , without assigning any hidden field it should give the search result

Comment: Please make sure that you do not make such a large number of typos when asking your question, it is hard enough to read your mind and understand what you need without the reading difficulties. Also, can you provide a data sample? One example for item and one for category?

Comment: therefore i passed a array object on json called desc where it give only values for categories and items that value is empty. and im trying to using that , check if a selected values have empty value on desc it should not assigning to a hidden field

Comment: You should also understand that `empty` and `not exists` are two entirely different things. Does your `desc` exists in item, and it is empty (`""`) or it does not exist as a property of an item?

Comment: its desc exists in item, and it is empty

Comment: well then try `if (ui.item.desc=="")` instead of `if(this.desc == ""  )`

Comment: ok , how can i make not assign a vlaue to hidden field (categories_id) if above condition is true. please advice @D. Kasipovic

Comment: Well assign it only if `ui.item.desc!=""`?

Comment: yes thats what i want , currently hidden field assigning for every selected value